# Where is the apache2 source is installed

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I am trying to install the Apache::Registry from cpan. And this gentleman needs the source for apache2, which it could not find. So, it is asking me about its whereabouts.

```
Enter `q' to stop search
Please tell me where I can find your apache src
 [../apache_x.x/src]
```

So, I installed the apache2 source.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 267 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/172 kB of archives.
After this operation, 975 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-dev.
(Reading database ... 175619 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-dev_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-dev (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up apache2-dev (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1) ...
```

Now, I restarted the install for Apache::Registry, but it still could not find the apache2 source. Oh well, needless to say, I had to look for it myself. I search in all directories where this source is expected to be to no avail. So, where is the default location where the apache source should be once install from the the apache2-dev package?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `apache2-dev` package just contains development (header) files, not the source itself (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/httpd/apache2-dev).

For the source code, you should either checkout the git / svn repos or visit https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi and download there the source.
There is no one soure folder, but split between the server itself (`server`) and modules, os-specific files etc.

Comment: `apt-get source apache2` gets you the precise sources for your currently installed Apache package, with all the Debian (or Ubuntu etc) patches.  For complex packages, this can be quite different from the upstream sources.